# Should I replace an AV accessory that was lost by someone else?

Tags: communication, negotiation, conflict

I work for an education oriented non-profit and recently we started letting people take A/V and photography equipment in exchange for a copy of the final product, so basically for free.

I'm in charge of monitoring the state of the returned equipment and recently someone lost a cable (TA3F-XLR to be exact) and I can't find it nor determine who exactly lost the cable and when.

Our boss is putting a halt on the "policy" and more or less starting to become unreasonable about finding the cable.

After some searching I found an adapter combo that would eliminate the need for the cable (And would actually be more convenient to store) but our accountant is refusing to give me the money to buy the adaptors until our boss gives the green light.

I'm now thinking of simply buying the adaptors out of my own pocket knowing that I will probably not be reimbursed but should I?

Will buying the adaptors out of my pocket bring any negativity in the near or far future or should I scrap the idea and continue trying to convince my boss to buy them?

Comment: What does "more or less starting to become unreasonable about finding the cable" mean?

Comment: @jcmeloni It's starting to affect not only me but my collegues and it's eating up a lot of time we could have spent on other projects. For example we have a conference we are hosting on Saturday and we need to concentrate on preparations for it yet we are spending time searching for that cable.

Comment: Oh, so you mean your boss is making you search for it a lot. Got it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm now thinking of simply buying the adaptors out of my own pocket
>   knowing that I will probably not be reimbursed but should I?

"Should" is something only you can decide. In general, a company (even a non-profit) should fund their own business needs. But this may be such small potatoes, that it does't matter much.

How much are the adaptors? If they are a few bucks that you can easily afford, there's little harm in buying them. If they are more than a few bucks, then do the work of convincing your boss that they are needed.

> Will buying the adaptors out of my pocket bring any negativity in the
>   near or far future or should I scrap the idea and continue trying to
>   convince my boss to buy them?

In might be viewed as a negative by your co-workers.

The downside here is setting a precedent that the company can get away with avoiding purchases by expecting employees to fund their expenses.

Even if this is something you can afford, perhaps your co-workers cannot, yet would feel pressured for similar purchases in the future.

Has a precedent already been established for these sorts of purchases? If so, you might want to be guided by the past.

Comment: It seems one of the coworkers managed to convince our boss to just get the adaptors and forget the cable. Marking this as the answer since this one is the closest to what I would do.

Answer (score 6):

OK, time for a little collectivism, here.  Tell the folks who used the equipment over the suspected loss window that you need to "Pass the hat," replace the cable, and get your boss to lighten up.

Your boss will (or should) see that as an act of contrition, i.e. "We aren't sure who lost the cable, but one of us did, and we take responsibility."

Then get the adapters.

FWIW:  I'm a video engineer, as well as a software developer, and know exactly the cable you're talking about.  You can buy them online for just over $20, depending on the length you need.  I've made several of them.  You're better off with adapters and just using regular old XLR cables.  It will make life and inventory a lot easier.

Comment: Problem with buying the original is that the cable is easy to get online, it's not so easy to get it offline since we don't have any shops that sells these. There are not many people here that have cards that can pay in foreign online stores.

Comment: You only need one card that can.  Do you want to solve the problem or inventory your roadblocks?

Answer (score 2):

Will buying the cable actually convince your boss to continue the loaner program? (If you're not sure, assign a percentage to yes and no, and scale the answers to the next two questions by those percentages.)

If so, is having the loaners available worth the cost of the cable, TO YOU?

If not, is getting rid of the distracting situation worth the cost of the cable, TO YOU, even if your boss continues to be grumpy about people not taking care of the equipment?

This is an exercise in expectation value. You've got to figure out whether the cost produces enough value, TO YOU, to justify the situation, and some of that is going to be a matter of guessing the odds of each possible outcome.

The other answer would be to institute a much more explicit check-out/check in program, where people are responsible for replacing anything in the kit that they lose or damage. It's their responsibility to make sure everything is present before they sign for it; it'll be someone else's responsibility (yours?) to check that everything has come back and appears to be OK. This will cost some man-hours, and some grief badgering folks about replacing, or paying for, anything that goes AWOL while in their hands.

Personal opinion: Unless the loaner program is actually within your nonprofit's official mission, or is a critical part of justifying having invested in the equipment in the first place, it probably isn't worth fighting to continue.

Comment: We already have a check-out program but people don't seem to want to check if the equipment they want is there or what they actually need (They are most of the time new to all of it). As for the check-in, sometimes people drop off the equipment and leave before it's time for me to get to work (I start at 11:00, we open at 8:30) so I don't get a chance to inspect it and then someone else takes part of the returned equipment or all of it.

Comment: @Lisiano Sounds like your program (I'm hesitant to even call it that) is poorly run, then. You either need more people (providing full coverage of office hours) responsible for handling the checking in and out of equipment, or you need to prevent access to the equipment when you're not available. Alternatively, make it clear that the last person who is *known* to have had the equipment will be responsible for replacing it. They can "check in" equipment when you're not there, but if somebody else takes it without you knowing and it goes missing, they're still going to have to take the blame.

Comment: Given this description, I'm not surprised management wants to shut it down. Run it responsibly, or don't run it.